# Aligning a button link within a container div

Tags: html, css

**I've created a button but I'd like to align it within a container div so it looks like:**

[image: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/image-for-stack.jpg]

My code is:

```
body {
    background-color: black;

}

.buttoncontainer {
     background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: 285px;
    height: 55px;
}

#button2:hover {
            background-color: #feb73b;
}

#button2 {
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fea710;
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 12px 32px;
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: .5px;
font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="buttoncontainer">
<a href="http://content.workbooks.com/free-trial-workbooks-crm" id="button2" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">start a free trial</a>
</div>
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by3pe47d/)

Any advice?

Apologies for not posting the links as pictures, I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks! I copied and pasted the button so must of missed that!

Comment: Any idea how to centre the orange button? @Will

Comment: Nah, fug CSS.  I usually bootstrap and call it a day.

Comment: I don't know what Bootstrap is, but I sure know I like the sound of it! Haha!

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/ learn how to use it properly and you will save yourself tons of stress.

Comment: Thanks Will, will check it out. Should I learn JS/JQ first?

Comment: You should learn everything.  Immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `margin-top: 20px;` from your #button2 `CSS`

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/by3pe47d/4/)

Thus the CSS would be like

```
#button2 {
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fea710;
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 12px 32px;
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: .5px;
font-weight: 400;
  /* margin-top: 20px; */
}
```

**UPDATE**

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/by3pe47d/5/)

I've changed the padding in the css as `padding: 14px 32px;`. So it gets centered.

Comment: Thanks @Lal - How can I centre the orange CTA post no margin?

Comment: Legend - I've just updated your fiddle altering the height and width so it looks even nicer.

Comment: oh great..:) could you please share the fiddle with me too..and please upvote the answer if it helped you..

Comment: All approved. Not sure why my questions been down voted!? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/by3pe47d/5/

Answer (score 0):

In button2' style :

- Remove margin-top
- Set display as block

Then :

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/by3pe47d/7/

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was swap the id's and class and I added the button 2 class to the html.

I added a position: relative; attribute to the container so the insides would stay inside.

Also if you want to change the position of it like left, right, etc. you can.

I also changed the top margain to 2px instead of 20px

http://jsfiddle.net/by3pe47d/10/

Html-

```
<div id="buttoncontainer">
<div class="button2">
<a href="http://content.workbooks.com/free-trial-workbooks-crm?utm_source=homepage&amp;utm_medium=newfreetrialbutton&amp;utm_campaign=neworangebutton" id="button2" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">start a free trial</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Css-

```
body {
background-color: black;

}
#buttoncontainer {
position: relative;
 background-color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
width: 285px;
height: 55px;
}

.button2 {    
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fea710;
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 12px 32px;
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: .5px;
font-weight: 400;
margin-top: 2px;
}

.button2:hover {
        background-color: #feb73b;
}
```

**Large Update**

Saw the image that was removed and made a thing that mimics it. It will stay formatted even if you use the left, right, etc. attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/by3pe47d/11/